# How to express the name of nearest subway station without using GoogleMap API? (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm a student who is studying iOS programming since few days ago.

I'm doing my small toy project for iOS subway application. I believe that doing a whole project alone is one of

the best way for improving new programming skill.

### What I want to make & Problems

The application that I want to make is a kind of subway application. The main function is knowing the next station when I'm on a subway. When I run the app, the only thing that appears on the first scene is **Name of the next subway station.** It is just the text, without any maps. So I think that I have to use GPS information for my current location and coordinates of all the subway stations for knowing the nearest station from my location. Also, I don't want to use Google API. I want to use Apple framework.

For that reason, I searched the Internet how to make this function . But I couldn't understand the whole flow for this app.

### What I'm searching on Apple Documentation

I found a documentation that may be important for solving my problem.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/converting_between_coordinates_and_user-friendly_place_names

According to this documentation, I should use Core Location, CLGeocoder, CLPlacemark. And Here's my scenario.

1. Save all the coordinates of subway stations in Seoul.
2. Take the coordinates of my current location with GPS.
3. Check the nearest subway station from my location.
4. Express the name of that subway station by text (on label).

But I don't have any ideas for approaching problems.

### Last Thing

There is one function that I made. It is about coordinates of my current location. Here's the code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading this long question written by my terrible English. Thank you.